# How to avoid fixed pattern noise in animations using Eevee?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

In cycles render settings there is a toggle to generate random noise seed values on each frame of the animation, which is useful in order to prevent fixed pattern noise.

Is there a similar feature in Eevee?

The 'animate' switch for generating a random value in the noise doesn't show up in Eevee render settings.

Comment: In Cycles, the seed toggle in question (I assume under Render/Sampling/Advanced?) does not "generate" noise but rather changes the randomness used at which the samples for each light path are determined. For example, for a ray hitting a sphere, sampling will occur randomly using the seed provided, some samples may be hitting the ground, some the light source etc. Eevee is not a ray tracer so such a seed does not exist. You best bet would probably be some sort of post processing noise filter.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for the clarification on how it works. It’s a shame because the noise itself isn’t at an unacceptable level and could be dealt with in the manner you suggest (by denoising). However since the noise is fixed pattern my experiments with denoising didn’t work so well for these shots. Hopefully I can invest in some better hardware soon and just up the samples :)